# Vulkan: serializing physical devices

Tags: vulkan

Let's say I have more physical devices supporting Vulkan (dedicated + integrated GPU, or 2 dedicated, or other possibilities). The user can choose the device to use in the options screen. I need to be able to persist his choice on disk.

What field can I use to uniquely identify a physical device across different executions?

- `vendorID` + `deviceID` is not enough: I could have 2 identical GPUs connected
- `deviceName` is not enough for the same reason
- `deviceLUID` is not guaranteed to be present, and may have the same problems as `deviceUUID` (below)
- `deviceUUID` looks like the correct choice, but the spec says:

  > While `VkPhysicalDeviceIDPropertiesKHR::deviceUUID` is specified to remain consistent across driver versions and system reboots, it is not intended to be usable as a serializable persistent identifier for a device. It may change when a device is physically added to, removed from, or moved to a different connector in a system while that system is powered down.

So... what should I use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`deviceUUID` is the best you're going to get.

Think it like this. If the `deviceUUID` matches a cached copy, then you are *certain* that it's the same device. And if the cached ID doesn't match *any* existing device, then either that hardware was removed or something radical happened. Either way, you need to pop up that dialog again to let the user decide what to do.

Comment: So you are saying that a device is not univocally bound to a uuid (as I cited from the spec), but that a uuid is univocally bound to a device. That is, if I change the configuration, some gpus may get a new uuid, but the old uuid of one of them will not be taken by another one. In that case, `deviceUUID` is good enough.

Comment: Since it's called "universally unique", then it's supposed to be "universally unique".